# How to update rows of MySQL without stored function?

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

My cloud server doesn't allow stored function/procedure, so how to do this?

My table was:

|id |Status |
| 1 | Good |
| 2 | Badd |
| 3 | Good |
| 4 | Good |

I wanted it to be:

| 1 | Good |
| 3 | Badd |
| 4 | Good |
| 5 | Good |

Can this be done with one line of statement?  Basically I want to change all id in rows where id>x to id+1.  In this case, x = 2.

### Update

Forgot to mention that id is unique so how to sort them desc then change?

Comment: `UPDATE tableName SET id = id + 1 WHERE id > 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE `table` SET id = id + 1 WHERE id > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
UPDATE yourtable SET id = id + 1 WHERE id > 1 ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

there is a known "bug" or "feature" that you will face if id is unique but order by desc will help you to avoid it.